# Signification du mot "pépétéesque"

Tags: vocabulaire, régionalismes, suisse

J'ai trouvé dans un journal local (Jura) Suisse datant de 1965 un article employant le mot "pépétéesque". J'ai été incapable d'en trouver une autre utilisation, encore moins une signification. Que signifie ce mot ? L'article peut être consulté [ici](https://www.e-newspaperarchives.ch/?a=d&d=LEJ19630823-01.2.3.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'un jeu de mot entre PTT-èsque, donc qui vient ou qui se rapporte aux PTT, et pépée, une jeune femme en argot.

Comment: *Pépée* (de poupée) ou son diminutif *pépette* (jeune fille)